# Convergence Problem in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I need to evaluate the following integral numerically for different values of `a`:

```
NIntegrate[w E^(-w/a)Sin[(w-0.001)100000]/((w-0.001)^2), {w, 0, ∞}]
```

If I define a small value for `a` and use the `MaxRecursion` and `AccuracyGoal` options I got no error:

```
a=0.000001
NIntegrate[w E^(-w/a)Sin[(w-0.001)100000]/((w-0.001)^2),
{w, 0, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

> 0.0000374967

But when I increase the value of `a` with any value for `MaxRecursion` and `AccuracyGoal`:

```
a=0.001
NIntegrate[w E^(-w/a)Sin[(w-0.001)100000]/((w-0.001)^2),
{w, 0, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

It gives the error:

`Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small`

It seems that a lot of questions arose regarding this problem in this community, but I didn't find any concrete solution. I really appropriate if anyone help me out with a solution?

Comment: The integral does not converge because there is a pole of order 1 at `w == 0.001`.  The first `NIntegrate`, which returns an answer without complaint, is wrong.  Now, do you want the Cauchy principal value?  (There is also an extra parenthesis in front of `Sin[]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why is it wrong? Yes. I want the principal value. By the way, thanks for the point on extra parenthesis.

Comment: Actually, I just assumed it was wrong, because the integral diverges and you didn't specify the `"PrincipalValue"` method.  But maybe it was doing the PV behind the scenes anyway.  By comparison, I get `6.63412*10^-7` for your first integral by the method in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming principal value:

```
Block[{a = 0.001, w0 = 0.001},
 NIntegrate[
  w E^(-w/a) Sin[(w - w0) 100000]/((w - w0)^2),
  {w, 0, w0, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
 ]
(*  -0.000052312  *)
```

Check (seems stable with increased precision):

```
Block[{a = 0.001 // Rationalize, w0 = 0.001 // Rationalize},
 NIntegrate[w E^(-w/a) Sin[(w - w0) 100000]/((w - w0)^2),
  {w, 0, w0, ∞},
  MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
  Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
 ]
(*  -0.000052311984060810925124564538411  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this integral can be done analytically.  I have ignored the 0.001 term as I suspect this is merely intended to improve the numerical behaviour.

```
Assuming[a > 0, Integrate[w E^(-w/a) Sin[(w) 100000]/((w)^2), {w, 0, Infinity}]]
```

gives the value

```
ArcTan[100000 a]
```